# MySql query graph data group - filter by data in column

Tags: mysql, group-by

i have two tables that i want to connect,
**this is table 1 "calendar"**

[image]

**this is table 2 "lead"**
[image]

I have this query

```
SELECT calendar.datefield AS DATE, IFNULL( count( lead.insertDate ) , 0 ) AS task FROM lead RIGHT JOIN calendar ON ( DATE( lead.insertDate ) = calendar.datefield ) GROUP BY DATE LIMIT 30
```

It works great, this is the result i get:

[image]

the thing is that i want to filter the data by `lead.lpid`.
I tried to add at the end of the query 'WHERE lead.lpid = x' and add at the begining of the query call for lead.lpid data like this:

```
SELECT lead.lpid, calendar.datefield AS DATE, 
        IFNULL( count( lead.insertDate ) , 0 ) AS task
        FROM lead 
        RIGHT JOIN calendar ON ( DATE( lead.insertDate ) = calendar.datefield ) 
        GROUP BY DATE LIMIT 30 WHERE lead.lpid =  9
```

but i get this error

```
.....'WHERE lead.lpid =  9' at line 5
```

I am kind'a lost. 
any help would be great!

Here is my SQL fiddle, I have tried query: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e5c34/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

place of Where is wrong:

```
SELECT lead.lpid, calendar.datefield AS DATE, 
        IFNULL( count( lead.insertDate ) , 0 ) AS task
        FROM lead 
        RIGHT JOIN calendar ON ( DATE( lead.insertDate ) = calendar.datefield )
        WHERE lead.lpid =  9 
        GROUP BY DATE LIMIT 30
```

**Note:** WHERE must be before GROUP BY

New Query as you want:

```
SELECT lead.lpid, calendar.datefield AS DATE, 
        IFNULL( count( lead.insertDate ) , 0 ) AS task
        FROM lead 
        RIGHT JOIN calendar ON ( DATE( lead.insertDate ) = calendar.datefield )
        AND lead.lpid =  9 
        GROUP BY DATE LIMIT 30
```

Comment: great, it did the work, but now i see only the dates which have data. is there a way to see all the dates, including rows that contain zero? like in the result i posted in the question?

Comment: of course, is there a simple way to retain the dates that contain '0' and also the leave the condition?

Comment: do you want records which have count 0 also?

Comment: it is useful if you provide sqlfiddle

Comment: @DavSev i don't know it is right or wrong.. I tried this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e5c34/11

Comment: wow man! this is exactly what i needed!  so you removed the call for the  `lead.lpid` after the select? great!   tnx!

Comment: @DavSev i added **AND lead.lpid =  9** insted of  **WHERE lead.lpid = 9**

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT lead.lpid, calendar.datefield AS DATE, 
        IFNULL( count( lead.insertDate ) , 0 ) AS task
        FROM lead 
        RIGHT JOIN calendar ON ( DATE( lead.insertDate ) = calendar.datefield ) 
        WHERE lead.lpid =  9 GROUP BY DATE LIMIT 30
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT lead.lpid,
       calendar.datefield AS DATE,
       IFNULL(count(lead.insertDate), 0) AS task
FROM lead
RIGHT JOIN calendar ON (DATE(lead.insertDate) = calendar.datefield)
GROUP BY DATE
HAVING lead.lpid = 9 LIMIT 30
```

use sql formater online: [sqlformat](http://sqlformat.org/)